# Mobile browser - Say smartphones to take 480px

Tags: responsive-design, viewport

The iPhone and other smartphone render a virtual window with of 320px. To work with this I used the meta-tag viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

The only problem is that my designer wants every smartphone to take 480px to render. Thus I tried `width=480px`, but I don't want tablets involved. Only smartphones should take this width of 480px. Is there a professional way to solve this problem (without PHP or JavaScript)?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "take 480px to render"? The meaning isn't clear.

Comment: (1) iPhones simulates a pixel-width of 320px
(2) The meta-tag viewport can influence this parameter (e.g. width=300px)
(3) I want the iPhone (and every other smartphone) to use width=480px but ONLY smartphones
(4) The viewport-meta-tag can't be limited to smartphones - tablets also take this width=480px